# .htaccess to redirect from root dir to PHP script

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I'm making a PHP project, which is online already and it's placed in:

```
www.mypage.com/dir/project.php
```

Most likely, it looks like:

```
www.mypage.com/dir/project.php?s=site&i=1&j=2&k=3
```

And i'm happy about that. However, now I'd like also to redirect it from

```
www.mypage.com/index.php
```

So, if you type:

```
www.mypage.com/index.php?s=something&i=fee
```

You will actually see this address, but executed script and its effect will be from:

```
www.mypage.com/dir/project.php?s=something&i=fee
```

I've tried so many .htaccess example files and yet no one worked as intended. Do you have any tips for me? Thank you very much.

Comment: Why u want to use htaccess? you can achieve it through simple php code as well.

Comment: I don't want to redirect to exact script path, i want to hide it intentionally. So if you mean changing header, it's not option. And I don't think including file is good idea, because, from my experience, it causes problems with relative paths...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With mod_rewrite, you translate an incoming request to a resource on the server. First make sure that the mod_rewrite is enabled on your server, and that you have the AllowOverride permission. You might need to restart Apache if you have not already done that.

After that you need to turn on rewriting using:

```
RewriteEngine on
```

Your .htaccess file is in your http root, so your rules will be relative to that. `RewriteRule`'s first argument will match anything after the domain+prefix, and before the query string. In `http://example.com/asdf?q=1`, `http://example.com` is the domain, `/` is the prefix, `asdf` is what will be matched and `q=1` can be matched through a condition using `%{QUERY_STRING}`

In your case we want to match `index.php` and rewrite it to `dir/project.php`. Since we don't change the query string, we don't have to do anything with it. The original query string will be appended to the rewritten request. It will look like this:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ dir/project.php [L]
```

We escaped the dot in index.php, because it is a regex. A dot in a regex matches any character, and we only want it to match the literal dot. `[L]` is a flag that tells Apache to stop this round of rewriting. It is more often than not good to have that behind your rule, unless you have a specific rule why you want Apache to continue rewriting.

With that, your rule should now work as expected. More basic information about mod_rewrite can be found [in the tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mod-rewrite/info) for the mod_rewrite tag, as well as [in the official documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).